# Google web app not running Javascript script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, time, scripting

Allright I have a problem, I am trying to make a google chrome app and ive got the basics working, what I have is a html file that loads another html file inside of it, the html file that is loads runs a script that displays the time. When I run it in my web browser it works fine, but when I run it via google chrome as an actual app the time doesn't show up, heres my code.

The file that the chrome app runs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>GimOS Emulator</title>
   </head>
    <body bgcolor = black>
    <center><font color="white">System Type: Emulated Mobile System (EMS) </font>   </center>
<center><IMG SRC = "Gimijes.png"><center> 
    <iframe src="menu.html" width=200 height=440></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the menu.html file that 'should display the time'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <title>GimOS Emulator</title>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor = white>
   <center><script type="text/javascript">
 function startTime()
{
 var today=new Date();
 var h=today.getHours();
 var m=today.getMinutes();
 var s=today.getSeconds();
 // add a zero in front of numbers<10
 m=checkTime(m);
 s=checkTime(s);
 document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
 t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
} 
 function checkTime(i)
{
 if (i<10)
{
 i="0" + i;
}
 return i;
}
  </script>
    </head>
       <body onload="startTime()">
     <div id="txt"></div></center>
   </body>
</html>
```

If anyone knows how to get the time to show up I would greatly appreciate it :D

Comment: By "google chrome app" are you talking about an extension?

Comment: Yes, probebly should have said that instead...

Answer (score 1):

Move your script into it's own file, eg. `menu.js`, and at the bottom add:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  startTime();
});
```

Then in your menu.html, just add this to the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
```

I'm more than sure it's the Content Security Policy (CSP) that's preventing the inline onload event to not trigger.

Comment: Its not working this is the content of the menu.js file incase i have done something wrong:                                                   function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
i="0" + i;
}
return i;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  startTime();
};

Comment: I forgot a parenthesis, woops.